# Is there anything like emacs tramp for shell (bash/zsh)?

Tags: bash, zsh

Say, we have a server where we use "userx" to deploy stuff and do some maintenance task. This user is being used by multiple team members. So, if I can not really modify the .bashrc or .zshrc the way I want it.

On the other hand, I am quite impressed by Emacs tramp. It lets me have my own Emacs configuration on my local system.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `.sabyarc` file (writable by you, readable by userx) and source it each time you log in as the user. Or, you can use a *group* for the maintenance task, so all the users involved can configure their own .rc files.